# Additional info below the main text on select option

Tags: html, jquery-select2

I used `select2` to produce my select option list like the snippet below.

```js
$(function(){
    $(".select2").select2();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Minimal</label>
    <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
        <option selected="selected">Alabama</option>
        <option>Alaska</option>
        <option>California</option>
        <option>Delaware</option>
        <option>Tennessee</option>
        <option>Texas</option>
        <option>Washington</option>
    </select>
</div>
       
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

What I want is, a subtext below the main text that searchable too.  when i want to search the option with value `Alabama`, I just need to type `Okay1`, but in the other hand I want to search with value `Alabama` only. Are there any plugins other than `select2` option library that support this kind of behavior ? ( Below is the image that i expected for the result )

[image: Additional info]

I have tried like the code below, but it didn't work that well :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Minimal</label>
    <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
        <option selected="selected">Alabama&nbsp&nbsp<h4 style="color: grey">Okay1</h4></option>
        <option>Alaska&nbsp&nbsp<h4 style="color: grey">Okay2</h4></option>
        <option>California&nbsp&nbsp<h4 style="color: grey">Okay2</h4></option>
        <option>Delaware&nbsp&nbsp<h4 style="color: grey">Okay3</h4></option>
        <option>Tennessee&nbsp&nbsp<h4 style="color: grey">Okay4</h4></option>
        <option>Texas&nbsp&nbsp<h4 style="color: grey">Okay5</h4></option>
        <option>Washington&nbsp&nbsp<h4 style="color: grey">Okay6</h4></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: you need something like dropdown menu check this link and style it like you want http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/jQuery-Searchable-Select-Menu-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-Dropselect.html

Comment: wow, thanks for the references (y)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could:

- encode the secondary property as an attribute of the `<option>` element
- use a [custom search](https://select2.org/searching) function, see `matchCustom` in snippet below
- use a [custom formatter](https://select2.org/dropdown) function, see `formatCustom` below

Working example, using state mottos as secondary attribute stored in `data-foo`, you can search by state name or motto:

```js
$(function(){
    $(".select2").select2({
        matcher: matchCustom,
        templateResult: formatCustom
    });
})

function stringMatch(term, candidate) {
    return candidate && candidate.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
}

function matchCustom(params, data) {
    // If there are no search terms, return all of the data
    if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
        return data;
    }
    // Do not display the item if there is no 'text' property
    if (typeof data.text === 'undefined') {
        return null;
    }
    // Match text of option
    if (stringMatch(params.term, data.text)) {
        return data;
    }
    // Match attribute "data-foo" of option
    if (stringMatch(params.term, $(data.element).attr('data-foo'))) {
        return data;
    }
    // Return `null` if the term should not be displayed
    return null;
}

function formatCustom(state) {
    return $(
        '<div><div>' + state.text + '</div><div class="foo">'
            + $(state.element).attr('data-foo')
            + '</div></div>'
    );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
.foo { color: #808080; text-size: smaller; }
</style>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Minimal</label>
    <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
        <option selected="selected" data-foo="We dare to defend our rights">Alabama</option>
        <option data-foo="North to the Future">Alaska</option>
        <option data-foo="Eureka">California</option>
        <option data-foo="Liberty and Independence">Delaware</option>
        <option data-foo="Agriculture and Commerce">Tennessee</option>
        <option data-foo="Friendship">Texas</option>
        <option data-foo="Bye and bye">Washington</option>
    </select>
</div>
       
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 11):

I would use [Bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/). It's a great library and already does every thing you want. No need to reinvent the wheel as they say!

You can search on both the title and description right out the box too.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group ">
                <label>Minimal</label>
                <select class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" title="Search title or description...">
                    <option data-subtext="description 1">Alaska</option>
                    <option data-subtext="description 2">California</option>
                    <option data-subtext="description 3">Delaware</option>
                    <option data-subtext="description 4">Tennessee</option>
                    <option data-subtext="description 5">Texas</option>
                    <option data-subtext="description 6">Washington</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu li small {
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 0 0 0;
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

[Here is a fiddle with a little bit of customisation](https://jsfiddle.net/xzgxxxmg/2/)

Comment: This is  a better approach rather than my accepted answer lol