# Dropdown menu showing total; need it to show the selected items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script that shows total price for each option in dropdown menu. Now I need to show the name of selected menu with the total.

You will find the script below that shows the total price. I need it to show the `name` in the `<option>`.

Any idea how to modify this to show the name of each dropdown selected?

```js
//<![CDATA[
$(function() {
  $("#type").on("change", function() {
    $("select.calculate option").eq(0).prop('selected', true);
    calc();
  });
  $("select.calculate").on("change", calc);
  $("input[type=checkbox].calculate").on("click", calc);
  function calc() {
    var basePrice = 0;
    newPrice = basePrice;
    $("select.calculate option:selected,input[type=checkbox].calculate:checked").each(function(idx, el) {
      newPrice += parseInt($(el).data('price'), 10);
    });
    newPrice = newPrice.toFixed(2);
    $("#item-price").html(newPrice);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="type" name="buyer" class="form-control input-lg form-el">
  <option value="">Service Needed</option>
  <option value="kite">Car Wash & Detailing</option>
    <option value="user">Mechanic visit</option>
  <option value="elect">Electrican visit</option>
  <option value="tyre">Tyre Service</option>
  <option value="bat">Battery Service</option>
</select>
<div style='display:none; ' id='business'>
  <select id="type2" name="buyername" class="form-control input-lg form-el calculate">
    <option data-price="0" value="">-- Select --</option>
    <option data-price="100" value="kite1">Car Wash exterior</option>
    <option data-price="150" value="kite1">Car Wash In & Out</option>
    <option data-price="1000" value="kite2">Full Detailing</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div style='display:none; ' id='tyrem'>
  <select id="type2" name="tyrem" class="form-control input-lg form-el calculate">
    <option data-price="0" value="">-- Select --</option>
    <option data-price="100" value="kite1">Road tyre problem rescue</option>
    <option data-price="50" value="kite1">4 Tyre pressure check and adjust</option>
    <option data-price="100" value="kite2">tyre 1 plug repair</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div style='display:none; ' id='batm'>
  <select id="type2" name="batm" class="form-control input-lg form-el calculate">
    <option data-price="0" value="">-- Select --</option>
    <option data-price="100" value="kite1">Battery rescue / jump start</option>
    <option data-price="150" value="kite2">Battery check , jump start or replace - price depends on battery</option>
  </select>
  <span id="item-price">0</span>
</div>
```

Comment: what could go wrong with your code ?

Comment: what exactly is your question?  Your code just shows a dropdown with names of services

Comment: I need the script to show the name of the selected <option> under the total , currently it shows the total price , i need to also show the name of selected <option> fields

Comment: like this ? @SalwaElBannan
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46441276/additional-info-below-the-main-text-on-select-option